# Uninstall new Relic package completely

Tags: uninstall, packages

I want to remove the package completely and start again as the server now has more 4 cores rather that 2, when new relic was first installed.

Have tried yum erase newrelic-sysmond , but this still doesn't remove the package.

Have tried yum reinstall newrelic-sysmond , but this still doesn't pickup the new cores.

Have tried yum clean newrelic-sysmond , and get Error: invalid clean argument: 'newrelic-sysmond'

This also displayes Package(s) newrelic-sysmond available, but not installed.

I want to remove it and reinstall brand new.

Thanks Peter

Answer (score 1):

The `remove` command to yum should remove the package completely. You may though find that e.g. config files that have been created or modified by you or the installation are not removed.

With the package installed you can use the `rpm -ql package` command to get a list of all the files and directories created by the package.

I would suspect that a config file is being left in place. You'll need to track it down and remove it.

Comment: Thank, I get this..
Last login: Sat Feb  7 10:33:33 2015 from 80.26.82.82
root@vded12318 [~]# yum remove newrelic-sysmond
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: newrelic-sysmond
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: centos.hyve.com
 * updates: mirror.econdc.com
Package(s) newrelic-sysmond available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
root@vded12318 [~]#

Comment: Sorted thanks very much for your help kind sir, have a great weekend, i'm out on my bike! hopefully you are.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to reinstall Newrelic for it to recognize new system resources. The daemon picks the changes up automatically.

But either way, the packages are removed with:

```
rpm -e $(rpm -qa | grep newrelic)
```